# Printing a string in the debugger shows its address, not its contents

Tags: objective-c, debugging, lldb

Why am I seeing a memory address instead of the "test" string I just added to the NSMutableArray? How do I see the actual object contents?

```
(lldb) p [autocompleteUrls addObject:@"test"]
(lldb) p [autocompleteUrls objectAtIndex:0]
(id) $8 = 0x00006e28
```

I've also tried casting it to NSString but that gave the error

```
(lldb) p (NSString*)autocompleteUrls[1]
error: C-style cast from 'id' to 'NSString' is not allowed
```

Comment: that cast is not correct anyway. you would need to cast to an `NSString*`, but you need to use `po` command for objective-c objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In LLDB
"p" is a short cut for "print" non-objects
"po" is a shortcut for "print-object" which prints objects

What you probably want is:
"po autocompleteUrls"
That wil print the contents of the autocompleteUrls object

"p [autocompleteUrls addObject:@"test"]"
prints the result of the method call which returns `void`.

For a good tutorial see Cocoa Is My Girlfriend:[Xcode LLDB Tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/12/13/xcode-lldb-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

This is a technical expansion of Zaph's excellent answer, just to make things seem a little less magical...

The lldb `p` command prints the memory contents of the expression you feed it, regardless of whether the expression resolves to an object or some other data type.

So for instance, if you have an ObjC object with ivar `p *object` will print the ivars.

The lldb `po` command evaluates the expression you feed it, and instead of printing it directly, it first tries calling the `debugDescription` method on it.  If the class of the object doesn't implement that method, it will then try calling the `description` method, and finally if the object is a CF object it will try `CFShow`.

For the really geeky what lldb actually does is call the Foundation routine `_NSPrintForDebugger` passing in the returned pointer, and that function is what implements the above described logic...

So the difference for objects is `p` prints the actual contents of the object, `po` prints the description of the object that the implementor of the class thought was appropriate for you to see.  Of course, most kit objects are pretty opaque, so the actual contents are often not very helpful, which is why the description method approach was added.